# Dart: get index of element in list 2 (element from list 1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 lists in DART

LIST 1: selected users

```
[{'name': name1, id:'123'}, {'name': name1, id:'123'})]
```

LIST 2: all users

```
[{'name': name1, id:'123'}, {'name': name1, id:'123'}) .... (much longer)]
```

I would like to know the index of each selected user of LIST 1 in LIST 2.
Is this possible?

I tried the indexWhere method.
But i keep getting the error:

```
error: The method 'contains' isn't defined for the class 'Map'.
```

Comment: in the examples the parantheses are wrong or? There is one } and one ) too much at the end isnt it?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I edited it. Thanks!

Comment: Do  you know the answer to this question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: see below. Dont know if it matches your problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case the structures in your lists are objects which are defined somehwere with equality operator overriden, you can do this:

```
class User {

  String name;
  String id;

  User(this.name, this.id);

 @override
 int get hashCode => name.hashCode ^ id.hashCode;

  bool operator == (o) => name == o.name && id == o.id;

  @override
  toString() {
    return "$name:$id";
  }

}

void main() {
  var list = [User("name1", "123") , User("name4", "888")];
  var list2 = [User("name1", "123") , User("name2", "234"), User("name3", "666"), User("name4", "888")];

  list.forEach((element) {
    print(list2.indexOf(element));
  });
}
```

This prints out all index keys for the selected Users (in my case). Perhaps there is a more elegant solution but it works. With indexWhere() you should be able to provide the equality comparision as a closure inside the function itself like:

```
  list.forEach((element) {
    print(list2.indexWhere((user) => user.name == element.name && user.id == element.id));
  });
```

With this, you can leave out the operator and hashcode override in user class.

In case you dont have a class, this should work too:

```
void main() {
  var list = [{"name": "name1", "id": "123"} , {"name": "name4", "id": "888"}];
  var list2 = [{"name": "name1", "id": "123"} , {"name": "name2", "id": "234"}, {"name": "name3", "id": "666"}, {"name": "name4", "id": "888"}];

  list.forEach((element) {
    print(list2.indexWhere((innerElement) => innerElement["name"] == element["name"] && innerElement["id"] == element["id"]));
  });
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is related, let say i have List condition = [1,2,3,4], and List buffer = [100,2,3,7,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0], and i would like to get the index of 1,2,3,4(from list condition), and it has to be 1,2,3,4 in order, it cannot be 1,4,3,2 .. what would be the best method to find it?

Answer (score 2):

The shortest solution would be:

```
List<int> indices = 
    [for (var e1 in list1) list2.indexWhere((e2) => e1["id"] == e2["id"])];
```

It's not efficient because you do a linear lookup for each element in `list1`.
It's better to create an index of the elements in list 1, so you can do efficient lookup by ID.

```
Set<int> selectedIds = {for (var e1 in list1) e1["id"]};
List<int> indices = 
    [for (i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) if (selectedIds.contains(list2[i]["id"])) i];
```